# Tomar el ID de un registro en una tabla PHP con JS

Tags: php, javascript

Cordial Saludo.

Necesito de la colaboración de ustedes.

Tengo una tabla php: con registros de BD

```
<td  id="<?php echo $row['Solc_idx']; ?>"><input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Procesar"></td>
```

el caso es que ese seria el ID, Del registro de la BD y lo capturo con JS, De la siguiente forma:

```
 $(function(){

  $('table').on('click', 'td', function(){ 

      console.log( 'Valor: ' + $(this).prop('id') );
  });
});
```

el caso es que asi de esa forma si me toma el ID, Pero me lo toma cuando haga click en cualquier parte del TD, osea de la fila, lo que quiero es que lo tome solo cuando haga click en el boton que esta en la fila de la tabla, no en toda la tabla

No se si me entiendan.

Gracias, quedo atento

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para ello debes indicar, en la delegación de eventos, que el click será sobre el botón, y no en el `td` en la línea `$('table').on('click', 'td', function()`, como es tu caso.

Aquí debes indicar que el click será sobre el botón, usando por ejemplo la clase. A continuación, a la hora de obtener el valor, debes indicar que el atributo que quieres recibir es el id del elemento padre (`td` es el elemento padre del `input`, que es el que está recibiendo el evento).

Te dejo un pequeño ejemplo;

```js
$("table").on("click",".btn", function() {
  console.log("ID del elemento td: ", $(this).parent().attr("id"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<td  id="1"><input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Procesar"></td>
<td  id="2"><input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Procesar"></td>
<td  id="3"><input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Procesar"></td>
</table>
```

Comment: Gracias amigo, Me funcionó eso era todo lo que necesitaba, Te agradezco